# Sample values from a list colum in spark dataframe

Tags: scala, list, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark-scala dataframe as shown in df1 below: I would like to sample with replacement from scores column(a List), based on counts in another column of df1.

```
val df1 = sc.parallelize(Seq(("a1",2,List(20,10)),("a2",1,List(30,10)),
("a3",3,List(10)),("a4",2,List(10,20,40)))).toDF("colA","counts","scores")

df1.show()
+----+------+------------+
|colA|counts|      scores|
+----+------+------------+
|  a1|     2|    [20, 10]|
|  a2|     1|    [30, 10]|
|  a3|     3|        [10]|
|  a4|     2|[10, 20, 40]|
+----+------+------------+
```

Expected output is shown in df2: from row 1, sample 2 values from list [20,10]; from row 2 sample 1 value from list [30,10]; from row 3 sample 3 values from list[10] with repetition.. etc.

```
df2.show() //expected output
+----+------+------------+-------------+
|colA|counts|      scores|sampledScores|
+----+------+------------+-------------+
|  a1|     2|    [20, 10]|     [20, 10]|
|  a2|     1|    [30, 10]|         [30]|
|  a3|     3|        [10]| [10, 10, 10]|
|  a4|     2|[10, 20, 40]|     [10, 40]|
+----+------+------------+-------------+
```

I wrote an udf 'takeSample' and applied to df1 but did not work as intended.

```
val takeSample = udf((a:Array[Int], count1:Int) => {Array.fill(count1)(
a(new Random(System.currentTimeMillis).nextInt(a.size)))}
)

val df2 = df1.withColumn("SampledScores", takeSample(df1("Scores"),df1("counts")))
```

I got the following run-time error; when executing

```
df2.printSchema()
root
 |-- colA: string (nullable = true)
 |-- counts: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- scores: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = false)
 |-- SampledScores: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = false)

df2.show()
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined   
function($anonfun$1: (array<int>, int) => array<int>)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:  
scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef cannot be cast to [I
at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:47)
```

Any solution is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should try and clarify what exactly in the output is not as intended. Also try to make your udf a bit more readable instead of a long line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the data type from `Array[Int]` to `Seq[Int]` in the UDF will resolve the issue:

```
val takeSample = udf((a:Seq[Int], count1:Int) => {Array.fill(count1)(
a(new Random(System.currentTimeMillis).nextInt(a.size)))}
)

val df2 = df1.withColumn("SampledScores", takeSample(df1("Scores"),df1("counts")))
```

It will give us the expected output:

```
df2.printSchema()
root
 |-- colA: string (nullable = true)
 |-- counts: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- scores: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = false)
 |-- SampledScores: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = false)

df2.show
+----+------+------------+-------------+
|colA|counts|      scores|SampledScores|
+----+------+------------+-------------+
|  a1|     2|    [20, 10]|     [20, 20]|
|  a2|     1|    [30, 10]|         [30]|
|  a3|     3|        [10]| [10, 10, 10]|
|  a4|     2|[10, 20, 40]|     [20, 20]|
+----+------+------------+-------------+
```